# ASP.NET MVC 4 Validation Summary/Text Without Html Helpers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get the validation text to appear either in a span below my input or in a summary div. I'm not using the HTML tags just plain inputs.

My HTML output is below:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="Regions[0].Name" 
       data-val="true" data-val-required="Region name is required" 
       id="Regions[0].Name" name="Regions[0].Name" 
       class="form-control input-validation-error" 
       aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" 
       aria-describedby="Regions\[0\]\.Name-error">

<span asp-validation-for="Regions[0].Name" class="text-danger"></span>

<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
```

My input is bound to a string inside of a list. The input validation css does fire and the field turns red, however no text appears. I checked and my client-side scripts are loaded.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Use an online validator like this one : https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

Comment: I'll use the helpers before I do that.

Comment: You need to fix the html.  The helpers will not fix the problem.

Comment: Then what needs fixed? Third-party won't do it. I'm using jQuery validate.

Comment: You are only validating.  Use online checker to make changes and verify the changes are valid html.  The online checkers will tell you the errors so you can manually make the changes and verify changes

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the inputs to include data-rule-required and data-msg-required:

```
<input type="text" data-msg-required="Region name is required" data-rule-required="true" id="@("Regions[" + i + "].Name")" name="@("Regions[" + i + "].Name")" class="form-control" />
```

And added the .validate method inside document ready:

```
$('#frm-region-maint').validate({
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        $(element).valid();
    },
    onkeyup: function (element) {
        $(element).valid();
    },
    errorElement: 'div',
    onfocusin: false,
    errorClass: 'input-validation-error',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass); 
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var summary = $('#error-summary');

        if (summary.find('p').length == 0) {
            summary.append($('<p>').prop({
                class: 'alert alert-danger',                    
            }).html(error[0].outerText));
        }            

    }
});
```

[image]